# Javascript Combine regex patterns preserving the regex result

Tags: javascript, regex, tokenize

I'm using this approach to obtain a combination of several patterns together:

```
var combinePatterns = function() {
  return new RegExp('(' + [].slice.call(arguments).map(function (e) {
      var e = e.toString()
      return '(?:' + e.substring(1, e.length - 1) + ')'
  }).join('|') + ')', "gi")
};
```

I then use it like

```
    var default_pattern = [/[^a-z0-9äâàéèëêïîöôùüûœç]+/];
    var other_patterns = ['\bla([- ]?la)+\b'];
    var patterns = [].concat(other_patterns).concat(default_pattern);
    // LP: pass along all regex patterns as argument
    patterns = this.combinePatterns.apply(this,patterns);
```

as showed in the following code:

```js
var combinePatterns = function() {
  return new RegExp('(' + [].slice.call(arguments).map(function(e) {
    var e = e.toString()
    return '(?:' + e.substring(1, e.length - 1) + ')'
  }).join('|') + ')', "gi")
};
var text = "salut comment allez-vous la-la-la";
var default_pattern = [/[^a-z0-9äâàéèëêïîöôùüûœç]+/];
var other_patterns = ['\bla([- ]?la)+\b'];
var patterns = [].concat(other_patterns).concat(default_pattern);
// LP: pass along all regex patterns as argument
patterns = this.combinePatterns.apply(this, patterns);
console.log(patterns);
var tokens = text.split(patterns);
console.log(tokens);
```

The problem is that when using the combined resulting regex, instead of the original regex, it seems I get different results. In fact if I combine with just the `default_pattern` and anything for the `other_patterns` I will get different results:

```js
var combinePatterns = function() {
  return new RegExp('(' + [].slice.call(arguments).map(function(e) {
    var e = e.toString()
    return '(?:' + e.substring(1, e.length - 1) + ')'
  }).join('|') + ')', "gi")
};
var text = "salut comment allez-vous la-la-la";
var default_pattern = [/[^a-z0-9äâàéèëêïîöôùüûœç]+/];
var other_patterns = [];
var patterns = [].concat(other_patterns).concat(default_pattern);
// LP: pass along all regex patterns as argument
var combined_regex = combinePatterns.apply(this, patterns);

console.log(default_pattern[0], text.split( default_pattern[0] ) )
console.log(combined_regex, text.split(combined_regex) )
```

While I would expect to get in bot cases the following array:

```
[
  "salut",
  "comment",
  "allez",
  "vous",
  "la",
  "la",
  "la"
]
```

Comment: You cannot combine regexps blindly using `|` alternation if the patterns overlap.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew correct. So in case of overlap which is the right way (like two pass matching maybe with some placeholder? In MOSES they do like this: https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder/blob/master/scripts/tokenizer/tokenizer.perl#L244

Comment: I'd use two passes.

Comment: Add `?:` after  `(`'s in two places to make groups non-capturing. This will make things better.

Comment: @AlexanderMashin I confirm that using `/(?:(?:[^a-z0-9äâàéèëêïîöôùüûœç]+))/gi` works.